# Setting volume separately for AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, avplayer, mpmovieplayer

I have a AVPlayer playing mp3 in background and a MPMoviePlayer visible to user playing another mp3 I am able to set volume for MPMoviePlayer using

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:cObj_VolumeLevel];
```

But it is changing volume for both AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayer I want to control both separately

Comment: Your call is setting the device's volume. The AVPlayer volume can be set independently so you might be better off reversing your situation and having the AVPlayer in the foreground app.

Comment: can't I use MPMoviePlayer with AVPlayer and have different volume controls?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController setVolume sets the device's volume which will adjust the volume of anything coming out of the ios device. AVPlayer goes one step beyond this in being able to individually set volume for each of its players.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this as an answer instead of a comment...

MPMoviePlayerController setVolume sets the device's volume which will adjust the volume of anything coming out of the ios device. AVPlayer goes one step beyond this in being able to individually set volume for each of its players.

Comment: I am using both in my project is there a way to control both separately so that when I reduce volume of AVPlayer it won't reduce the volume of MPMoviePlayerController and vice versa

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any other way to say this. The AVPlayer volume can be changed independently, the MPMoviePlayer volume is the same as the device's volume. If you reduce the volume of the AVPlayer it won't reduce the MPMoviePlayer's volume but NOT vice-versa... if you reduce the MPMoviePlayer's volume it WILL reduce the AVPlayer's volume as it is reducing the overall volume.